# Panel inside a Panel: autoScroll not working

Tags: extjs, view, scroll, extjs4, scrollbar

I have this view (DetailsContainer, first class in code section of this question) with two items inside (MetaDataPanel, Preview), but autoscroll doesn't work in MetaDataPanel (follow the code). 
So when I put some items inside MetaDataPanel, autoscroll doesn't work...
PS: the content of MetaDataPanel is generated dinamically adding element to this Panel...
Any suggests?

```
Ext.define('DP.view.DetailsContainer' ,{ 
id: 'DetailsContainer',
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
alias : 'widget.DetailsContainer',
collapsible: true,
// margins:'5 0 5 5',
split:true,
layout: {
    type: 'accordion',
    align: 'stretch',
    pack  : 'start'
},

initComponent: function() {


    Ext.apply(this, {

        items: [{
            xtype: 'MetaDataPanel',
            flex:1
        },{
            xtype: 'Preview',
            flex:2     
        }]
    });

    this.callParent(arguments);
}
});


Ext.define('DP.view.MetaDataPanel' ,{
id: 'MetaDataPanel',
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
alias : 'widget.MetaDataPanel',
title : 'MetaDati', 
layout: 'fit',
autoScroll:true, //TODO: autoscroll not working
initComponent: function() {
    Ext.apply(this, {
        items: [{
            xtype: 'component' ,
            html: 'Nessun File o Cartella selezionata. Selezionare un elemento per visualizzare i metadati!',
            margin: 5,
            style: {
                color: '#000000'
            }
        }]
    });
    this.callParent(arguments);
}
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to specify autoScroll on a container with a fit layout. The child will always fit the size of the container, it will never be bigger, so you can never scroll. You want the autoScroll on the inner component.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it make sense for an accordion panel to scroll. What you should do instead is set the inner component to to scroll. Look at your code slightly changed to reflect that idea:
http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/jmHEj/

Comment: It works! but when I add some elemnt dinamically, it doesn't work again! any suggests? maybe some "doLayout()"?

Comment: no extjs 4 has done away with do layout.  can you be a bit more specific what element you are adding and to what component?

Comment: I'm adding this: form = Ext.widget('form', {autoScroll:true,layout:{type: 'vbox',align: 'stretch'},border: false,
fieldDefaults: {labelAlign: 'top',labelWidth: 100,labelStyle: 'font-weight:bold'},defaults: {margins: '0 0 10 0'} ... });

Comment: can you fork that JSFiddle and add your code that doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

Most easy (or lazy) is to set config `autoScroll` as a default - so that it will be inherited:

```
defaults: {autoScroll: true},
```